# What is the best approach to scale nodejs that consumes kafka messages

Tags: node.js, multithreading, apache-kafka

I have a node application that consumes Kafka messages, makes some long operations, and finally, sends the result to another microservice through Kafka message.

**what is the best approach to improve my application scalability so it can process more Kafka messages per second? and why?**

1. Using the clustering module of node js to create multiple instances that connect to Kafka using the same consumer group. (I think it should enhance the scalability by cores count)
2. Using a thread pool of the worker threads node js module. and distribute the Kafka consumed messages across the worker threads.
3. any other suggestions?

Comment: You could use both. Multiple instances can use thread pools per instance

Comment: can you clarify the advantage of that approach? as far as I understand, the ideal count of the worker thread is equal to the effective cores which will enhance the scalability by cores count. and for the clusters, the max instances will be equal to cores. so I think with constant cores count i will not gain any extra benefit.

Comment: But there are other processes running on your hosts, so one physical machine won't have access to use all the cores for your Node process, but other machines might have more cores available than others. So, that means you could _dynamically_ provision multiple threads across several machines

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you for your reply
Each worker thread can use a separate CPU. which means that by having the correct count of worker threads per machine we can utilize all of the available CPUs. and we can figure out the count of machine threads dynamically using `os.cpus().length`.
based on that, clustering doesn't have any extra advantage.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What happens when that application or host crashes? Do you not want a backup instance (on a separate machine)? If not, then you don't need a cluster... That has nothing to do with Kafka, though